# Change p:watermark color dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, primefaces

I am doing a project using primefaces.

In my project i need to change the color of `p:watermark`(primefaces) when i click the `p:commandButton`.

I tried but does not work.

Here, I added my tiny code:

**Sample Code:**

```
<p:inputText id="userNameField" update="info"/>
<p:watermark for="userNameField" value="#{...}" id="userLabelWaterMarkId"/>

<p:commandButton id="loginButtonId" onclick="showLoginBox();" update="info">
</p:commandButton>
```

**JQuery**

```
 function showLoginBox()
   {
     $(".ui-watermark").css("color", "red");
   }
```

Any idea?

Comment: i dont see any class for P:watermark as .ui-watermark.is it there in your original code?

Comment: try $("#userLabelWaterMarkId").css("color", "red");

Comment: i already tried which u posted.but not this too work. and i saw this .ui-watermark style code in another one stackoverflow thats why i selected.its not my original code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change an input's HTML5 placeholder color with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score 0):

The ui-watermark class is there in [OLD browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-placeholder) since PrimeFaces uses some backwardscompatibility 'hack' that the jquery-ui watermark does as well. Modern browsers do it differently and need styling differently... For those browsers, your question is a duplicate of the link below.

See also:

- [Change an HTML5 input's placeholder color with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610497/change-an-inputs-html5-placeholder-color-with-css)

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".ui-watermark").css("color", "red");
```

Here color represents color of the font.
If you need to change background-color use like this.

```
$(".ui-watermark").css("background-color", "red");
```

make sure that watermark is having class called `.ui-watermark`,its not there in the code you posted.

Comment: Where did he said he need to change background-color? He said color specifically.

Comment: i need to change the text color,not the background-color...and .ui-watermark is not working.

Comment: there is no watermark element (so also no id) in modern browsers ON THE CLIENT

Answer (score -1):

You should create an on click function like this:

```
function showLoginBox(){
    $("#userLabelWaterMarkId").css("color", "red");
}

$('#loginButtonId').on('click', showLoginBox())
```

or

```
$('#loginButtonId').on('click', function() {

    $('#userLabelWaterMarkId').css('color', 'red');

})
```

binding JS event inside HTML is not a best practice. You need to create the event binding code in your javascript file.

Comment: there is no watermark element (so also no id) in modern browsers ON THE CLIENT